# How can I do such a typical unittest?

Tags: python, django, testcase

This is a simple structure in my project:

```
MyAPP---
        note---
               __init__.py
               views.py
               urls.py
               test.py
               models.py
        auth--
              ...
        template---
                   auth---
                          login.html
                          register.html
                   note---
                          noteshow.html
                   media---
                           css---
                                 ...
                           js---
                                 ...
        settings.py
        urls.py
        __init__.py
        manage.py
```

I want to make a unittest which can test the noteshow page working propeyly or not.

The code:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class Note(TestCase):
    def test_noteshow(self):
        response = self.client.get('/note/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, '/note/noteshow.html')
```

The problem is that my project include an auth mod, it will force the unlogin user redirecting into the login.html page when they visit the noteshow.html.

So, when I run my unittest, in the bash it raise an failure that the response.status_code is always 302 instead of 200.

All right though through this result I can check the auth mod is running well, it is not like what I want it to be.

OK, the question is that how can I make another unittest to check my noteshow.template is used or not?

Thanks for all.

django version: 1.1.1

python version: 2.6.4

Use Eclipse for MAC OS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just login a user for each test. The best way to do this is to use a `setUp()` method that creates a client, creates a user, and then logs user in. Also use a `tearDown()` method that does the reverse (logs out user and deletes user).

The methods `setUp()` and `tearDown()` are run automatically for each test in the set of tests.

It would look something like this:

```
class Note(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.new_user = User.objects.create_user('blah', 'blah@blah.com', 'blah')
        self.new_user.save()
        self.client.login(username='blah', password='blah')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.client.logout()
        self.new_user.delete()
 
    def test_noteshow(self):
        response = self.client.get('/note/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, '/note/noteshow.html')
```